# how to use drupal_write_record. my db doesnt update when form submits

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

Im using drupal and im trying to create my own form in a block.

Ive wrote a module which creates a block with a submit button.

When the form is submitted im trying to write the values to my db.

im using this code

```
function my_module_my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    block_example_insert_credits($credits_record);
}

function block_example_insert_credits() { 
  global $user;
  $credits_record = array(
    'nid' => $node->nid,
    'uid' => $user->uid,
    'credits' => $form_state['values']['bids'],
  );
  drupal_write_record('example_table', $credits_record, 'nid');
}
```

the form submits and validates, and the table and columns exist in my db. When I submit the form nothing gets sent to database, why isnt my code correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things not quite right:

1. You're not passing any parameters to `block_example_insert_credits()`
2. You have no reference to `$credits_record` in `my_module_my_form_submit()` so nothing would be passed to the insert function anyway.
3. You're trying to access `$form_state` from a function in which it doesn't exist
4. You don't have a reference to the node object anywhere so you can't use it. `$node` isn't a globally available variable, if you want a node object it will have to come from a value save in your form or from the `menu_get_object()` function (if the block is being displayed on a node page).

Try this code and see if you have any luck:

```
function my_module_my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  block_example_insert_credits($form_state);
}

function block_example_insert_credits($form_state) {
  global $user;
  $node = menu_get_object();
  $credits_record = array(
    'nid' => $node->nid,
    'uid' => $user->uid,
    'credits' => $form_state['values']['bids'],
  );
  drupal_write_record('example_table', $credits_record, 'nid');
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

i'm a drupal novice so apologies if i'm wrong...isn't it the $node or &$form_state that should be passed to the insert method from form_submit?......maybe you could check by using watchdog for the credit records array to check values are passed properly...cheers